# Insert into select from different tables on SIMILAR key update

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

So I have this query which updates on duplicate key and makes average of values from different table

```
    INSERT INTO maintable (NomeSquadra, Nazione, Campionato, DateTime, `1`, `X`, `2`)
    SELECT NomeSquadra,
           Nazione,
           Campionato,
           DateTime,
           AVG(NULLIF(`1`, 0)) AS `1`,
           AVG(NULLIF(`X`, 0)) AS `X`,
           AVG(NULLIF(`2`, 0)) AS `2`
    FROM
      (SELECT NomeSquadra,
              Nazione,
              Campionato,
              DateTime,
              `1`,
              `X`,
              `2`
       FROM snai3
       UNION ALL SELECT NomeSquadra,
                        Nazione,
                        Campionato,
                        DateTime,
                        `1`,
                        `X`,
                        `2`
       FROM b888) AS subquery
    GROUP BY NomeSquadra ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE `1`=
    VALUES(`1`),
          `X`= VALUES(`X`),
                     `2`= VALUES(`2`)
```

Is there a way to update on a similar key instead of duplicate key?

My problem is that instead of having one row with the name I have 3. I only want it to insert one row on the key "NomeSquadra" and avg the 1, X, 2

```
+------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------+------+------+------+
| NomeSquadra                  | Nazione      | Campionato     | Datetime   | 1    | X    | 2    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------+------+------+------+
| Tottenham - Sheffield UTD    | Inghilterra  | Premier League | 2019-11-09 | 1.25 | 2.01 | 3.15 |
| Tottenham - Sheffield        | Inghilterra  | Premier League | 2019-11-09 | 1.26 | 2    | 3.21 |
| Tottenham - Sheffield United | Inghilterra  | Premier League | 2019-11-09 | 1.21 | 1.97 | 3.17 |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------+------+------+------+
```

I don't know if this is possible, I searched everywhere but can't find a solution

Comment: If this was PostgreSQL, you could have used CTE to delete the rows and then insert back their AVG. With MySQL, I think you will have to use a separate (e.g. temporary) table to calculate the AVGs, and then update the original table with the AVGs.

Comment: Just normalise your data

Comment: Yeah, but my question was if it was possible to do it with similar values instead of duplicates only.